# comparision between basic nature of CH3O- and -OH

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

when comparing the basic nature of $CH_3O^-$ and that of $OH^-$. I found two arguments. one favoring the more basic nature of $CH_3O^-$ and the other favoring the basic nature of $OH^-$. so which of them is true. and why isn't the other condition correct.

the conditions are as follows.

1. since $CH_3OH$ is a stronger acid when compared to $H_2O$, its corresponding conjugate base should be weaker. that is $CH_3O^-$ is a weaker base when compared to $OH^-$
2. since there exists a methyl group on the $O^-$ the electron density on $O^-$ increases hence it is a better base when compared to $OH^-$ since H doesn't have any +I effect /

Comment: Point 1) seems out of nothing

Comment: What makes you think CH3OH is a stronger acid than H2O ?

Comment: Their pKa values